# How can I programmatically access the Http routes table from the ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I need to iterate over the the **Http route table** from the **ASP.NET Web API** from within an **ASP.NET MVC** Controller action method in the same project. All the routes work fine. I've been playing around with the `HttpRouteCollection` but its always empty.

I've been trying things like this: -

```
var httpRoutes = new IHttpRoute[10];
new HttpRouteCollection().CopyTo(httpRoutes, 0); 

foreach (var route in httpRoutes)
{
  // ...
}
```

Or this : -

```
var httpRoutes = new IHttpRoute[10];
new HttpRouteCollection("api/").CopyTo(httpRoutes, 0); 

foreach (var route in httpRoutes)
{
  // ...
}
```

How do I get to this info?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm essentially wanting to display all the possible API routes. Kinda like the WEB API help page does. As I'm typing this I realise I should probably start by looking at that code. But if you can help I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be accessing the Global.Configuration.Routes instance of HttpRoutecollection instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Thanks Darrel, I thought I'd already tried that, obviously not, but the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes has everything I need.